# How to get the hostname of an ip address by using asio library?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to get hostname from UDP endpoint. However I do not know whether boost.asio supports IP->hostname conversion. Anyone can answer my question?

Comment: What would you call "the" hostname? In practice IP-addresses can be routable under very many names, many not under the control of the party owning the server.

Comment: my teacher asked me to do so.

Comment: Do you know (can you guess) which "hostname" is expected as the result? Do you know how to get that hostname via other means (e.g. some shell command?)

Comment: i need get hostname on both windows and android. Cross Platform is no 1 priority i need to do.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: sounds like gethostbyaddr can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

[getnameinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo) is what you want.

```
getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr), hostname, sizeof(hostname), NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: ok. why asio library does not provide a C++ interface for this?

Comment: Because there's no gain? By the way, it **does** a decent job of abstraction https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp#L2571

Comment: That is still C style API. Also it is implemented in detail/impl namespace which means it is not a public interface. I think asio library should provide a host_name() method in asio::ip class.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<asio.hpp>
#include<exception>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
try
{
    asio::io_service io_service;
    asio::ip::udp::resolver rsv(io_service);
    for(const auto &ele : rsv.resolve(asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::address_v4({192,168,1,163}),0)))
    {
        std::cout<<ele.host_name()<<'\n';
    }

}
catch(const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr<<e.what()<<'\n';
    return 1;
}
}
```

I have found out how to get host name by ip. Just directly resolve endpoint by using ip address